# Black and white image on hover with orange container over it

Tags: html, hover

I want on hover effect exactly like this:
http://www.imagebam.com/image/44d2ce431709029
So, image becomes black and white, orange colour is over image, and text appears over whole content.

This is my html code

```
<section class="project_main_container">
    <div class="row row-margin no-gap-r">
        <div class="project_container col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-margin">
            <a href="cordoba_work.php">
            <img class="project_image" src="images/home-grid4.jpg"></img>
                <div class="project_media">

                    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    <p>Branding</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


</section>
```

and this is css

```
.project_main_container {
width: 100%;
}

.project_image {
width: 100%;
}

.project_media {
position:relative;
}

.project_media p {
 margin:0;
padding:0;
 text-align:center;
position:absolute;
top:55%;
width:100%;
transform:translate(0%,-50%);
-webkit-transform:translate(0%,-50%);
-ms-transform:translate(0%,-50%);
color:#FFFFFF;
  font-style: italic;
font-family: georgia;
display:none;
}
.project_media h3   {
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
top:45%;
width:100%;
transform:translate(0%,-50%);
-webkit-transform:translate(0%,-50%);
-ms-transform:translate(0%,-50%);
color:#FFFFFF;
font-family:Arial;
text-transform:uppercase;
display:none;
}

.project_container:hover img {
/* filter: brightness(0.4);
-webkit-filter:brightness(0.4);
-ms-filter:brightness(0.4);*/
opacity: 0.3;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;

}
.project_media:hover {
 background-color: #f57b20;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making the image as background of the parent div? then the child can have an opaque orange background on hover

Answer (score 0):

Well, to make an image black and white, please check: http://thenewcode.com/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS

As for adding the orange overlay effect, you can make a parent div with your `img` and another `div` for the overlay/text like so:

`parent > img + overlay-div`

Now for this to work we have to make the `overlay-div` above the `img` and to be hidden until there is a hover effect. The `overlay-div` will be the same height and width as the parent and also with an opaque background to make the orange color effect using `rgba` color

Another method is making the `img` as background so the structure will be simpler:

`parent > child`

See example:

```css
html {font-family: Arial}
  
.parent {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}

.child {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgba(215, 81, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  opacity:0;
  transition:.3s;
  color:#FFF;
}

.parent:hover .child {opacity:1;}

.method1 {
  background:url(http://rs252.pbsrc.com/albums/hh23/minakomika/Artistic-Nature-29558.jpg~c200);
}

.method2 {
  position: relative;
}

.method2 img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Method #1 - Background</h2>

<div class="parent method1">
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p>Branding</p>
  </div>
</div>
  
  
<h2>Method #2 - Img</h2>

<div class="parent method2">
  <img src=" http://rs252.pbsrc.com/albums/hh23/minakomika/Artistic-Nature-29558.jpg~c200" alt="" />
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p>Branding</p>
  </div>
</div>
```